# Google Calendar API quickstart.html "Uncaught [object Object]" only on Chromium on Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-calendar-api

The javascript example of the Google Calendar API, [quickstart.htm](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js)l, works perfectly in Chrome or Edge on a Win10 PC.  But when I run it in Chromium-browser on a Raspberry Pi (3) served by apache2, This code in quickstart.html:

```
gapi.client.init({
discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
clientId: CLIENT_ID,
scope: SCOPES
  }).then(function () {
// Listen for sign-in state changes.
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

// Handle the initial sign-in state.
updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
  });
```

I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught [object Object]
    (anonymous function) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:70
```

Looking at the pretty-printed, minified source for this line 70 in the developer tools, the error comes from this api code:

```
var tp, $o, ep, Yo;
tp = function(a) {
_.D.setTimeout(function() {
    throw a;  // <<<<<< This is marked with a red 'x'
    }, 0)
}
;
```

This looks like something timed out and it looking for an error handler.  But I am still very new to javascript, so I'm not sure where such a handler might need to go.  I don't know if something needs to wait and try again or just wait or if the script 'defer' property used by quickstart.html is broken in Chromium.  Any help someone could give is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved the issue, but I ran into this a few days ago and after 2 days of troubleshooting and almost ripping of all my hair I remembered I hadn't put down my external IP which I used to view the page on the raspberry into the Google Dev Console as a redirect uri for the client ID and it solved this error.